# Polynomial implementation in Golang

Tags: formatting, go, numerical-methods, symbolic-math

I am writing a numerical analysis library in golang for which I need to implement a polynomial struct. Here is the source code:

```
package numerical

import (
    "strconv"
)

type Poly struct {
    Coeffs []float64
}

func (p *Poly) Str() string {
    d := p.Deg()

    if d == -1 {
        return "0"
    }

    s := ""
    if p.Coeffs[d] == -1 {
        if d == 0 {
            s += "-1"
        } else {
            s += "-"
        }
    } else if p.Coeffs[d] != 1 || d == 0 {
        s += strconv.FormatFloat(p.Coeffs[d], 'g', -1, 64)
    }
    if d == 1 {
        s += "x"
    } else if d > 1 {
        s += "x^" + strconv.Itoa(d)
    }
    for i := d-1; i >= 0; i-- {
        if p.Coeffs[i] > 0 {
            s +=  " + "
            if p.Coeffs[i] != 1 || i == 0 {
                s += strconv.FormatFloat(p.Coeffs[i], 'g', -1, 64)
            }
        } else if p.Coeffs[i] < 0 {
            s += " - "
            if p.Coeffs[i] != -1 || i == 0 {
                s += strconv.FormatFloat(-p.Coeffs[i], 'g', -1, 64)
            }
        }
        if p.Coeffs[i] != 0 {
            if i == 1 {
                s += "x"
            } else if i > 1 {
                s += "x^" + strconv.Itoa(i)
            }
        }
    }

    return s
}

func (p *Poly) Deg() int {
    i := len(p.Coeffs) - 1
    for ; i >= 0 && p.Coeffs[i] == 0; i-=1 {
    }
    return i
}

func (p *Poly) Eval(x float64) float64 {
    val := p.Coeffs[0]
    pow := 1.0
    for i:=1; i <= p.Deg(); i+=1 {
        pow *= x
        val += p.Coeffs[i]*pow
    }
    return val
}

func PolyAdd(p, q Poly) Poly {
    var big, small, r Poly
    if p.Deg() > q.Deg() {
        big = p
        small = q
    } else {
        big = q
        small = p
    }
    r = big
    for i := 0; i <= small.Deg(); i+=1 {
        r.Coeffs[i] += small.Coeffs[i]
    }
    return r
}

func PolySub(p, q Poly) Poly {
    degp := p.Deg()
    degq := q.Deg()
    big := degp
    if degp < degq {
        big = degq
    }
    r := Poly{make([]float64, big+1)}
    for i := 0; i <= big; i++ {
        if i <= degp {
            r.Coeffs[i] = p.Coeffs[i]
        }
        if i <= degq {
            r.Coeffs[i] -= q.Coeffs[i]
        }
    }
    return r
}

func PolyMul(p, q Poly) Poly {
    m, n := p.Deg(), q.Deg()
    r := Poly{make([]float64, m+n+1)}
    for i := 0; i <= m; i++ {
        for j := 0; j <= n; j++ {
            r.Coeffs[i+j] += p.Coeffs[i]*q.Coeffs[j]
        }
    }
    return r
}

func PolyDiv(a, b Poly) (Poly, Poly) {
    var q Poly
    for b.Deg() <= a.Deg() {
        dega := a.Deg()
        degb := b.Deg()
        qc := a.Coeffs[dega]/b.Coeffs[degb]
        qp := dega - degb
        qi := Poly{make([]float64, qp+1)}
        qi.Coeffs[qp] = qc
        a = PolySub(a, PolyMul(qi, b))
        q = PolyAdd(q, qi)
    }
    return q, a
}
```

A few things that I observed about the code are:

- The `Poly.Deg` is a method. I should probably make a non-method field (*what are they called?*) for that purpose, but then I will have to create a `Poly.UpdateDeg` which will set the degree for a new polynomial, and then I will have to call this `UpdateDeg` in all the other functions like `PolyAdd`, `PolyMul` etc. Is their a better way to achieve this.
- The `Poly.Str` method, which basically pretty-prints the polynomial looks very complicated. The purpose of this method is to return a string containing the polynomial in human readable form. For example, the polynomial `{-1, 2, -1}` will give `-x^2 + 2x - 1` (pay special attention to the leading coefficients and spaces around `+` and `-`). Can this method be simplified?

Any other suggestion/improvements are welcome, in particular, I would like to know if the code is idiomatic Go. I am new to Go, and would like to learn the Go-way of doing things.

**EDIT**: Here is the code on [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/sM79zEdIFV8) (slightly modified to run on Playground).

Comment: @200_success I am sorry, but your edit was at the same time as my update and it undid my update. So I had to rollback to my update but I have included the tag suggested by you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is missing automatic tests.

One test case you definitely need is to ensure that `PolyAdd` and the related functions do not modify their arguments. As far as I can see by reading the code, the current version of `PolyAdd` modifies the bigger of its arguments, which is unexpected.

The reason that the argument is modified is that slices are essentially pointers, and when passing them as arguments, their content is not copied.

You should define a constructor function `NewPoly(deg int)` to hide all the implementation details. Using this constructor will also solve the aliasing problem mentioned above.

Regarding the long code for `Str`, you can merge some of the duplicate code:

```golang
    c := p.Coeffs[i]
    if c == 0 {
        continue;
    }

    if c > 0 {
        s += " + "
    } else {
        s += " - "
    }

    if (c != 1 && c != -1) || i == 0 {
        s += strconv.FormatFloat(c, 'g', -1, 64)
    }
    if i > 1 {
        s += "x^" + strconv.Itoa(i)
    } else if i == 1 {
        s += "x"
    }
```

By extracting the expression `p.Coeffs[i]` into a variable, the code gets a bit cleaner.

If you need to speed up `Str`, use a `strings.Builder` instead of the `+=` operator.

Comment: I added a section on making `Str` shorter.